# How to develop react app via online development

Tags: reactjs

I'm just curios about this situations creating app with React Js. Is there any way to build directly on the hosting Cpanel not on localhost during development? I don't know if this question is right I'm new about this  but how about if were done developing on local then build and upload to server, if there is small changes of the application then you can't change directly on the server because the code is bundle and minified. I tried to search on google and watch tutorials but can't find it. I know there nothing wrong to build on local, however I like the point that while i'm building I know it works very well and see it on live then if there is small changes I could change directly.

Apologies to my curiosity. Thanks in advance for your ideas and correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if react requires bundling. It is not so big itself. One useful way that you can do it, just build your react app in local, then create a git repository, push it to there then from there you can pull it to your server by connecting your server with SSH.

This way may require some installations on server side again with SSH connection. You can search the details about the way I suggest you.

Comment: I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Yeah it can work. Im currently working like this in my projects.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciating your curiosity, I can think of two possible (not at all recommended though) solutions.

## 1. Dump jsx

React applications requires a build process primarily for JSX syntax. It is developer intuitive. If there is no jsx in your code no need to build. So, this jsx

```
return (
  <h1>Greetings, {this.props.name}!</h1>
);
```

Should be written as this js

```js
return React.createElement('h1', null, 'Greetings, ' + this.props.name + '!');
```

## 2. Setup development environment in Server

This is a risky one. There're possible security issues.

Its like have a centralized code base on the server that anyone with access can modify.
Here, you can edit files & run build task directly on server.

## Notes:

Today's basic development flow is `code -> build -> deploy`. Better stick with it for serious applications.